# iTextSharp - Improve HTML Image

Tags: c#, itext

I have a routine that prints a PDF of HTML code.  It works very well except the embedded image DPI is too low, so the resolution is very poor.  Is there a way I can set the stylesheet to use a higher DPI?

```
    HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);

    string fontpath = Server.MapPath("/Fonts/arialuni.ttf");
    FontFactory.Register(fontpath, "Arial Unicode MS");

    StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.SIZE, "6pt");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H3, HtmlTags.SIZE, "10pt");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H5, HtmlTags.SIZE, "6pt");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

    parser.SetStyleSheet(styles);
```

HTML code -

```
div style="text-align: left; margin-left:40px;">
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 141px;"><img alt="" src="http://ephoms-prod.azurewebsites.net/images/eph_graphics/eph_logo_small.png"/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><h4>Order Summary</h4></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Deckard said, "Enhance!" There is nothing a style sheet can do to change the amount of information displayed in a picture. The best thing you can do is find a much higher resolution version of the file.

Comment: Change your image tag to `<img width="68" height="50" alt="" src="http://ephoms-prod.azurewebsites.net/images/eph_graphics/eph_logo.png"/>` and you'll get the larger image placed into a smaller space and thus increase your DPI. If you actually control this site and image you can further kick up the pixel width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the image size solved my problem.